Branch Lock Obfuscator integration in Dsl gradle
I am facing error while adding this plugin in dsl gradle because it don't support apply plugin format.
Apply plugin: net.branchlock.obfuscation.android.BLAPlugin
branchlock {

    branchlockApiUrl = 'https://branchlock.net/api'

    bearerToken = '' // The bearer token of your Branchlock account

    projectId = 'default-android' // The project ID of your Branchlock project

} 

I want to integrate this properly in dsl gradle.
